# Get Facebook access_token from URL

Tags: java, servlets, facebook, httprequest

I implemented a Facebook app with Java servlets. I wonder how I can read the access token from the HTTP request sent by Facebook after authentication.

The request sent to me by Facebook looks like this: `http://myserver/app/servlet#access_token=3108888%7C2.AQByEGAdEk7D5hs3.3600.130400.1-10005014%7C3XTVE&expires_in=4317`

How can I read the access token (which is a fragment and not a parameter) in my Java servlet? If it was a parameter I would do:

```
request.getParameter("access_token);
```

Comment: Solved! I found a way to make Facebook send me the request with a "real" http parameter instead of a fragment.

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve it? -Joni

Comment: IT would be nice if you described the solution too.

Comment: @Mirko it is encouraged that you answer your own question if you found the solution on your own.  That way others with the same problem can follow your example.

Answer (score 0):

To make facebook send the request which contains access_token in http parameters, one needs to change the `resoponse_type` parameter in request. It is of two types `code` and `token`.  If we pass `token` the `access_code` will be in [url fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and if we pass `token` it will be request parameter with key as `code`.

See: [Constructing a URL to the OAuth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/#Parameters)

For server side handling of `access_code` e.g. in some servlet, it is needed to send `request_type` as `code` else it can be handled only in client side through javascript.